# Static route monitor

Tags: routing, statistics

Good morning, 
I am walking into a global network and am being tasked with implementing a dynamic routing solution. There are quite a few static routes on our Core switches. Ripping out static routes that are moving traffic is somethign I want to avoid.  I am wondering if anyone has an idea of a command on Cisco L3 switches, that I can monitor the traffic on specific static routes? Maybe show statistics of the amount of traffic that's utilized the static route?

For example, "sh ip sockets, or sh ip traffic" but only displaying the traffic that traverses the static route.

Thanks everyone and have a great one!

Comment: It sounds like you need to implement NetFlow.

Comment: Do you intent to use those stats to check if some traffic still use the static route while there's already dynamic routing implemented? (this will not work unless you tweak the administrative distance)

Comment: I do plan on using the stats to best determine the routes that are necessary, and those that need to be phased out.

Comment: @RonMaupin I believe that you are correct. I also have Solarwinds NPM at my disposal as well. On Twhack, it looks like their "Network Engineer Toolset" is their recommendation.

Comment: Figured this out with Standard ACLs with a permit A.B.C.D log applied to the vlans.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is accomplished with a standard ACL hit-count. Add "log" modifier to the ACL and when you sh access-list, you will see a match counter. Bingo!

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.